# 2x Juniper SRX300 RETH interface on multiple interfaces

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx

We have two SRX300 boxes in a chassis cluster. I have configured the RETH0 interface for WAN communication and assigned 1 port on the first unit and 1 port at the second unit. I have setup reth1 interface for LAN communication, I want to assign two ports per unit for 2x switch uplink. The second port configured with reth1 does not seem to work.

I have configured it with the configuration below. Port Ge-0/0/3 is working, but Port Ge-0/0/5 is not working. I can't ping 10.31.10.1.

```
    reth1 {
    redundant-ether-options {
        redundancy-group 1;
    }
    unit 0 {
        family inet {
            address 10.31.10.1/24;
        }
    }
}
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/3 {
        gigether-options {
            redundant-parent reth1;
        }
    }
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/5 {
        gigether-options {
            redundant-parent reth1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you configure the reth's into the security zones? Please show config.